# Borrow checker doesn't want a reference to outlive a shorter lifetime than its content

Tags: rust

I have some code that preprocesses some data; a part of it is truncating a mutable slice but the borrow checker doesn't seem to like it, for an odd reason. Here's a minimal example:

```rust
struct C<'a>(&'a mut [u8]);

impl<'a> C<'a> {
    fn f<'b>(&'b mut self) where 'a: 'b {
        self.0 = &mut self.0[..]
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c90eacff3f166419683649858448988c)

Just to clarify the lifetimes situation: in the actual code I have some request data, and the code that handles requests calls the mentioned preprocessing function. The idea is that `'a` is the lifetime of the request, and `'b` is the tiny lifetime of the `mut` borrow into this function. So while flipping the bounds into `'b: 'a` (or only having `'a`) satisfies the borrow-checker here, it's not what I want (and makes the `mut` borrow longer than it should be, so it merely makes the borrow checker angry later at call-site).

The error message I'm getting from this is: "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements", and one side of the conflict is what's tripping me: it complains that the borrow of `&mut self.0` "cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` [..] so that reference does not outlive borrowed content". But the borrowed content has lifetime `'a`, so why shouldn't it be able to outlive `'b`?

Comment: Definitely a non-trivial solution to what seems a trivial problem. The application here looks like: `self.0 = &mut std::mem::replace(&mut self.0, &mut [])[..];` It's more complicated than it looks because indexing can *theoretically* panic (even though it can't in this case) and then it would be unclear whether `self.0` were invalidated or not. `mem::replace` fixes this by temporarily substituting a dummy value (an empty slice). This is sometimes called the Indiana Jones trick.